# islands and gaps ordering issue MYSQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, gaps-and-islands, row-number, mysql-8.0

I am trying to use partition by & row_number() to count  consecutive duplicate values for a given date range.Essentially its attempting to capture "streaks" If there is a break in the streak the count should start over when the value occurs again.

### To reproduce these results here is the code:

```
    CREATE TABLE partion_test (
    daily DATE,
    response_short_name VARCHAR(10)
    
);

INSERT INTO `partion_test` (`daily`, `response_short_name`) VALUES
('2020-09-21', 'A'),
('2020-09-25', 'A'),
('2020-09-26', 'A'),
('2020-09-27', 'A'),
('2020-09-28', 'A'),
('2020-09-22', 'B'),
('2020-09-20', 'C'),
('2020-09-23', 'C'),
('2020-09-24', 'C');





SELECT 
daily,
response_short_name
 ,row_number() over (partition by response_short_name order by daily) as seqnum 
FROM (

select
daily,
response_short_name

 FROM partion_test  
order by daily  limit 1000
) A;
```

### HERE IS THE CURRENT OUTPUT

```
|   daily    | response_short_name | seqnum |  |
+------------+---------------------+--------+--+
| 2020-09-21 | A                   |      1 |  |
| 2020-09-25 | A                   |      2 |  |
| 2020-09-26 | A                   |      3 |  |
| 2020-09-27 | A                   |      4 |  |
| 2020-09-28 | A                   |      5 |  |
| 2020-09-22 | B                   |      1 |  |
| 2020-09-20 | C                   |      1 |  |
| 2020-09-23 | C                   |      2 |  |
| 2020-09-24 | C                   |      3 |  |
+------------+---------------------+--------+--+
```

### HERE IS THE DESIRED OUTPOUT

```
 +------------+---------------------+--------+--+
|   daily    | response_short_name | seqnum |  |
+------------+---------------------+--------+--+
| 2020-09-20 | C                   |      1 |  |
| 2020-09-21 | A                   |      1 |  |
| 2020-09-22 | B                   |      1 |  |
| 2020-09-23 | C                   |      1 |  |
| 2020-09-24 | C                   |      2 |  |
| 2020-09-25 | A                   |      1 |  |
| 2020-09-26 | A                   |      2 |  |
| 2020-09-27 | A                   |      3 |  |
| 2020-09-28 | A                   |      4 |  |
+------------+---------------------+--------+--+
```

Ive been scratching at my brain for a while on this. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I think you just need `ORDER BY A.daily`

Comment: Your basic problem is that a subquery has no irderbecause tables are by nature unsrteed, so add a order by to the subquery

Comment: @nbk adding the order to the subquery still has the "seqnum" out of order

Comment: sometimes the order is "optimized" so use in addition  LIMIT 10000

Comment: @nbk I appreciate your quick responses to my question. I am still getting the wrong output

Comment: show us the original data as they are needed, i still don't get what yu need,

Comment: @nbk Let me clean up my question. One moment

Comment: Your table contains 9 rows, but your expected output 10 rows. Why?

Comment: @nbk why would you add an order to the subquery?

Comment: @forpas I corrected. the question makes sense now. If you have any suggestions Im all ears.

Comment: @LandonCarr your data nw makes mre sense an it is much clearer i changed my answer

Comment: @ysth i had anpother query in mind, so i hinted in the wrong direction, but theimpaler git the answer first, i made another approach

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select *,
  row_number() over(partition by grp order by daily) as seqnum  
from (
  select *,
    sum(inc) over(order by daily) as grp
  from (
    select *,
      case when lag(response_short_name) over(order by daily) = response_short_name
        then 0 else 1 end as inc
    from partion_test
    order by daily
  ) x
) y
order by daily
```

Result:

```
 daily       response_short_name  inc  grp  seqnum 
 ----------- -------------------- ---- ---- ------ 
 2020-09-20  C                    1    1    1      
 2020-09-21  A                    1    2    1      
 2020-09-22  B                    1    3    1      
 2020-09-23  C                    1    4    1      
 2020-09-24  C                    0    4    2      
 2020-09-25  A                    1    5    1      
 2020-09-26  A                    0    5    2      
 2020-09-27  A                    0    5    3      
 2020-09-28  A                    0    5    4
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iJLDYTUDEWG53FXR1LejsR/0):

Answer (score 0):

Your data doesn't fit your result, so it is quite diffcult t achieve your result

> ```
>     CREATE TABLE partion_test (
>     daily DATE,
>     response_short_name VARCHAR(10)
>     
> );
>
> INSERT INTO `partion_test` (`daily`, `response_short_name`) VALUES
> ('2020-09-21', 'A'),
> ('2020-09-25', 'A'),
> ('2020-09-26', 'A'),
> ('2020-09-27', 'A'),
> ('2020-09-28', 'A'),
> ('2020-09-22', 'B'),
> ('2020-09-20', 'C'),
> ('2020-09-23', 'C'),
> ('2020-09-24', 'C');
> ```

> ```
> select `daily`,`response_short_name`,
>        row_number() over (partition by `response_short_name`, grp order by `daily`) as row_num
> from (select t.*,
>              (row_number() over (order by `daily`) -
>               row_number() over (partition by `response_short_name` order by `daily`)
>              ) as grp
>       from partion_test t
>      ) t
>      ORDER BY `daily`
> ```
>
> ```
> daily      | response_short_name | row_num
> :--------- | :------------------ | ------:
> 2020-09-20 | C                   |       1
> 2020-09-21 | A                   |       1
> 2020-09-22 | B                   |       1
> 2020-09-23 | C                   |       1
> 2020-09-24 | C                   |       2
> 2020-09-25 | A                   |       1
> 2020-09-26 | A                   |       2
> 2020-09-27 | A                   |       3
> 2020-09-28 | A                   |       4
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3a124ba655007e02e34b688f571b2647)*